# Using the Microsoft Help Viewer 1.X from Delphi

Tags: delphi

Has anyone got any hints that will allow me to integrate the Microsoft Help Viewer with a Delphi Application (2009 onwards).

Thanks

Comment: Still using HTML Help created by Help&Manual with my Delphi 2009 Apps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Introducing MS Help Viewer 1.0](http://www.helpware.net/mshelp3/intro.htm) and [Microsoft Help System Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776252.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

i assume you mean HtmlHelp, since `WinHelp` is deprecated, and stopped shipping with Windows 5 years ago.

Here's the code i add to my `ApplicationEvents` object's `OnHelp` event handler:

```
function TdmGlobal.ApplicationEvents1Help(Command: Word; Data: Integer; 
   var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean;
var
    HelpFile: string;
    LocalFile: string;
    HCommand : word;
begin
    CallHelp := False;
    Result := False;

    //i've named the help file the same as the executable, but with CHM extension
    HelpFile := ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName, '.chm');
    if not FileExists(HelpFile) then
        Exit;

    //Starting in 2003 HtmlHelp will no longer work from a network drive.
    //Copy the file to the local machine's temp folder if it's sitting on a network share
    if PathIsNetworkPath(HelpFile) then
    begin
        LocalFile := IncludeTrailingBackslash(GetTemporaryPath)+ExtractFilename(HelpFile);
        if (not FileExists(LocalFile)) then
        begin
            try
                CopyFile(PChar(HelpFile), PChar(LocalFile), False);
            except
                Exit;
            end;
        end
        else
        begin
            if (GetUncompressedFileSize(HelpFile) <> GetUncompressedFileSize(LocalFile)) then
            try
                CopyFile(PChar(HelpFile), PChar(LocalFile), False);
            except
                //Exit; eat it
            end;
        end;

        HelpFile := LocalFile;
    end;

    {translate WinHelp --> HTMLHelp}
    case Command of
    HELP_CONTENTS:
        begin
            HCommand :=  HH_DISPLAY_TOC;
            Data := 0;
        end; {HELP_CONTENTS..}
    HELP_CONTEXT : HCommand :=  HH_HELP_CONTEXT;
    HELP_CONTEXTPOPUP : HCommand := HH_HELP_CONTEXT;
    HELP_FINDER : HCommand := HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC;
    HELP_KEY : HCommand :=  HH_DISPLAY_INDEX;
    HELP_QUIT :
        begin
            HCommand :=  HH_CLOSE_ALL;
            Data := 0;
        end; {HELP_QUIT..}
    else
        begin {default}
            HCommand := HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC;
            Data := 0;
        end; {default..}
    end; {case Command..}

    hhCtrl.HtmlHelp(GetDesktopWindow(), HelpFile, HCommand, Data);
end;
```

With `hhCtrl.pas` containing a number of constants, as well as the function:

```
function HtmlHelp(
       hwndCaller: HWND; 
       szFile: AnsiString; 
       uCommand: UINT; 
       dwData: DWORD): HWND; stdcall; external 'hhctrl.ocx' name 'HtmlHelpA'; {external API call}
```